# Crontab in alpine image

Tags: docker, cron, alpine-linux

I want to create a cronjob inside alpine image, which will run every 15 seconds.
The command in dockerfile for this is

```
RUN echo "*/15 * * * * * /etc/init.d/aws-env-setup.sh" >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
```

Below is the file after image start.

```
# do daily/weekly/monthly maintenance
# min   hour    day month   weekday command
*/15    *   *   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/15min
0   *   *   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/hourly
0   2   *   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/daily
0   3   *   *   6   run-parts /etc/periodic/weekly
0   5   1   *   *   run-parts /etc/periodic/monthly
*/15 * * * * * /etc/init.d/aws-env-setup.sh
```

The cronjob is not running.

How can I successfully create cronjob inside alpine containers. My aim is to run the cronjob only once, 15 seconds after container starts .
Last line of my sh file, I want to run under cron is -
`crontab -r`

Comment: Is cron running? Please extract a [mcve] first, including the full instructions you use to start it. Also, how do you determine that it "is not running"?

Comment: tl;dr: [cron does not provide sub-minute resolution](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html).

Answer (score -1):

I am annoyed by cron. It is so standard, so common, and should be so straight forward, but the reality is, that it to often just a mess. I formyself said screw cron, and make myself a python service based on this helper

```
def cron(delay, task):

    # delay in seconds
    next_time = time.time() + delay

    while True:
      try:
          task()
      except Exception:
          traceback.print_exc()
          print(str(traceback.print_exc()))

      next_time += (time.time() - next_time) // delay * delay + delay
      time.sleep(max(0, next_time - time.time()))
```

Set delay to 15, your task is

```
cmd = "/etc/init.d/aws-env-setup.sh"
task = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

And make a service out of it. You can use your linux for it, but as you already work inside docker, you could set a docker restart policy and let docker take the work to handle it as daemon.

Comment: [cron does not provide sub-minute resolution](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html).